# How to pass a token to backend server with ingress nginx kubernetes

Tags: http-headers, nginx-ingress

So we have backend servers that I need to pass the token back to.  This isn't doing auth to another server that then redirects the backend servers are the endpoints for everything.

We've discovered that we can pass through whatever header that we want to do but as soon as I set the header to access_token it does not pass that through as we've proven this with an echo server testing various headers.

We added this to our ingress resource

```
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-response-headers: access_token
```

But it still does not pass the header back to the backend servers.

Everything is enabled for our ingress pods with a configmap.  We do not want to add each and every single header to the config map and as I understand thats not needed.  We also want our developers to be able to manage the headers themselves within their ingress resources.

I've read the docs but I must be missing something somewhere that is bluntly obvious haha.

Thank you all for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that you need to enable this in the configmap for your ingress pods

```
  enable-underscores-in-headers: "true"
```

With that enabled we can now pass through headers with an underscore.